# ClickOnce Losing Manifest

Tags: clickonce

All,

Not technical here so pardon the way I ask this.  We have a ClickOnce application that is demonstrating very strange behavior.  Starting on 11/16 we began to receive reports from some users that while attempting to open the application in question they were being prompted to re-install it.  Problem is that we have released not updates and can identify no MS updates that have been applied to computer.

Now for the strange part.  If I have the users re-boot their computer the will not receive the install message again....here's the really weird part....for the rest of the day even if they shutdown, reboot, etc... 20 times.  Only the next morning when they get into work will they be prompted with a re-install message again.  Once they reboot they no longer get that for another full day.

It's as if the ClickOnce shortcut is losing the location of the manifest and is therefore, by design, looking back out on the server and requesting an install.  This is also represented by the fact that the icon that we direct it to use, which is also stored in the install directory, is not being used on the first boot of the day but will re-appear after the reboot is complete.

In some ways I'm leaning toward this being some sort of date issue.  Again, the user can shut their computer down 20 more times during the same day and they will never get the install message.  Only after we've crossed over to the next day do they receive it on initial startup.

Does anyone have any idea on what we should be looking for here.  Any words of wisdom would be much appreciated.